# Code Coverage Tool Branch Coverage tree illustrator for Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, debugging, code-coverage

Is there any code coverage tool or debugger tool for Java that displays the branch coverage as a tree? I just thought that it is easier for the developer to debug and cover the code when there's a visual representation of the code.

Thanks

I tried using the JaCoCo report generation xml to try if the data can be translated into individual branch path but it seems that the data was all summary of the coverage.

Comment: I believe JaCoCo also generates HTML pages, with links that allow you to drill down and see individual files and lines where issues occur.